Should the target be standardized in gradient descent?
Suppose that we have a general loss function that depends on some parameters $w$ (e.g. neural network weights):
$$L_w =\frac{1}{N} \sum_i \ell(\hat{y}_i, y_i)$$
Is it beneficial to standardize the target in addition to features?
That is, should we prefer to optimize $L_w'$:
$$L_w' =\frac{1}{N} \sum_i \ell\left(\hat{y}_i, \frac{y_i-\bar{y}}{\sigma} \right)$$
over $L_w$?
Related questions
In the accepted answer of this question, it is stated that:

Normalizing the output will not affect shape of $f$, so it's generally
not necessary.

where $\hat{y} = f_w (x)$. However, during training we optimize the loss function and as such, the shape of $f$ is irrelevant.

This will obviously depend on the loss function. Accordingly, this question makes little sense as stated. What specific loss function(s) do you care about?

@g g I am more interested in the effect of standardizing for gradient descent. I will edit the question appropriately.

Bear in mind your general loss function $\ell$ can absorb your intended output normalizing. And for consistency purpose if you normalize the ground truth output, then you also need to normalize the model predicted output in the same loss function.
